# What the output matrix should be of two classes segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02924. The task is nuclei segmentation with the only point annotation. The mask has positive pixels assigned to centroids of nuclei, and negative pixels assigned to Voronoi boundary.

> In this scheme, positive labels are given to the pixels corresponding to point annotations, while negative labels are assigned to pixels on Voronoi boundaries that can be obtained by distance transform with
> point annotations

Besides, the threshold to determine positive pixel from network is 0.5.

> The threshold to determine positive pixels from f(I) is 0.5

So, what the output of the network and mask(label) matrix look like?

I thought:

Output: (width, height, 1), if the value greater than 0.5, then it is positive pixel(centroid), otherwise it is negative value(boundary).

Mask: (width, height, 1), I am lit confused in here because there are actually 3 categories in here, background, positive, negative, but it didn't assign label to background.

> Then, binary cross-entropy losses are evaluated and averaged over the labels and corresponding pixel outputs.

Or should these two matrices be 2 channels? One channel for the positive label, and one channel for the negative label.

If so, why we need the threshold? Does it mean, if the value of a pixel greater than 0.5, then it is seen as a positive pixel or negative pixel in the first channel, second channel respectively? Rather than value > 0.5 is a positive class, otherwise a negative class.

I am new to segmentation, so some definitions are not clear.